# unsigned char pixel_intensity[] to image; C code, Linux

Tags: c, linux, image, pixel

I have a data array of pixel intensity (e.g. `unsigned char pixel_intensity[4] = {0, 255, 255, 0}`) and I need to create image in **C code on Linux** (Raspberry Pi).

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Note that your introductory 'I need your help' sentence is really not needed; if you didn't need help, you'd not be asking the question (most likely).  You should also show (explain) what you've tried.  The C variable definition is a promising start; it gives you one pixel.  An image consists of lots of pixels.  Which image file format did you have in mind?

Comment: Use [Netpbm format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format). `fprintf(imagefile, "P3 1 1 255 %d %d %d\n", pixel_intensity[0], pixel_intensity[1], pixel_intensity[2]);`

Comment: What do these pixel_intensity represent? Grayscale, for 4 pixels? (And if so: is '0' "no color", i.e. black, or "no ink", i.e. white?) RGBA values? (And if so: is the last value to be interpreted as Alpha?) Something else: Lab, HSB, CMYK, or some packed 16- or 32-bit format? Monochrome, 8 black/white pixels per value?

Comment: Sorry for bad example. I have a cmos sensor with 1310x720 active pixels. Each pixel is representing by value 0-255 (grayscale, where 0 is black, 255 white).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the netpbm format as it is very easy to program. It is documented [here](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm).

I have written a little  demonstration of how to write a simple greyscale ramp to a 100x256 image below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

   FILE *imageFile;
   int x,y,pixel,height=100,width=256;

   imageFile=fopen("image.pgm","wb");
   if(imageFile==NULL){
      perror("ERROR: Cannot open output file");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   fprintf(imageFile,"P5\n");           // P5 filetype
   fprintf(imageFile,"%d %d\n",width,height);   // dimensions
   fprintf(imageFile,"255\n");          // Max pixel

   /* Now write a greyscale ramp */
   for(x=0;x<height;x++){
      for(y=0;y<width;y++){
         pixel=y;
         fputc(pixel,imageFile);
      }
   }

   fclose(imageFile);
}
```

The header of the image looks like this:

```
P5
256 100
255
<binary data of pixels>
```

And the image looks like this (I have made it into a JPEG for rendering on here)

[image]

Once you have an image, you can use the superb `ImageMagick` ([here](http://www.imagemagick.org)) tools to convert the image to anything else you like, e.g. if you want the greyscale created by the above converted into a JPEG, just use `ImageMagick` like this:

```
convert image.pgm image.jpg
```

Or, if you want a PNG

```
convert image.pgm image.png
```

You can actually use the PGM format images directly on the web, by convention, the MIME type is `image/x-portable-graymap`

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly to store images to disk, but is here any way, how draw images continuously (as a video).

Comment: I know very little about the Raspeberry Pi. It does seem to have a Broadcom chip that supports OpenGL ES, so maybe that is something you could explore. You could post another question on Stack Overflow specifically about programming video output on a Pi. Also have a look here: http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_VideoCore_APIs

Comment: This looks useful for you too http://raspberrycompote.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/low-level-graphics-on-raspberry-pi-part_9509.html