# How can I open and parse a png pixel by pixel?

Tags: c++, image

I'm just wondering how I could go about iterating through each pixel of an image? I know I can open the file as I could any other, but it's not in a 'readable' format.

For example, let's say I have: `world.png (1920/1080)`

How do I go about parsing it within two for loops?

Comment: Have you looked at `opencv`?

Comment: Okay so, I actually 'need' to iterate through it on my own. I know opencv is an option, but I'm trying to benchmark a `native c++` app against one written in CUDA. So, I'm actually just wondering how to open it up in a readable format.

@JasonMc92 Every single answer on this entire website can be found in a Google search with enough time. This is a website `dedicated` to programming help...

Comment: @Kris, I know. I've been here a while. :) My information is just the typical rules of good StackOverflow questions, in my own words. I prefer it to close-voting everything, as is the style of some.

Comment: Is your image colour or greyscale? What OS are you using?

Comment: If you want to make life easy for yourself, I would suggest http://stackoverflow.com/a/24599122/2836621 ... or ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/22374310/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a library to achieve what you want. In this case the library is `libpng`. See the "reading" section of the manual: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt

As noted by @Ben in the comments there is also a C++ wrapper: http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/doc/0.2.7/

Comment: *Have to*? what is the library made of? Fairy dust?

Comment: It's a good programming rule: "don't reinvent the wheel". Writing a compliant PNG reader is not something you do in a couple of work days. Anyway: I replaced "have to" with "should", if you prefer.

Comment: Heh, I'm being a little pedantic, but for the benefit of the OP...the rule is more realistically "don't reinvent an identical wheel". Get a bike wheel design from someone else, but if you're going to make a flying car, you'll probably need to reinvent the wheel to handle the landings. ^,^ That said, I'd agree that this is one of those bike wheel scenarios.

Comment: @JasonMc92 I totally disagree with you suggestion to the OP. I cannot imagine what a "flying car" could be in this scenario.

Comment: It's a general rule about the "don't reinvent" logic, not specific to parsing a PNG. An example of what I'm talking about would be one of my company's projects, where we need specific behavior and performance out of an SVG parser. None of the existing libraries have it, so we're writing our own (though we ARE using Xerces for the XML). If a library fully meets one's needs, use it. If it mostly meets one's needs, contribute to it and use it. If it doesn't, write your own (an action often mislabeled as "reinventing"). That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini A streaming PNG reader implemented in hybrid software-firmware-FPGA that expects and corrects common encoding errors in the incoming stream, and implements extensions on top of PNG for proprietary purposes, delivering the pixels (and partial pixels) in a real-time manner over a proprietary protocol?  ... the answer remains "why in the world would you solve that problem", but there can be crazy situations where the wheels out there really don't solve your problems.

Comment: I might add, very few people can imagine the flying car scenario until they walk headlong into it. See also, Eric Raymond's "sendmail".

Comment: @Yakk I don't think it is possible to correct "common encoding errors" in a PNG format because it can contain compressed data hence a single bit error could be impossible to recover. Anyway an ipotetic "common encoding error recovery" could be implemented on the raw data before using libpng functionality. The rest of your scenario can be implemented by libpng: both the streaming and the extensions are covered by the library.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini As an example, suppose you had PNGs with the wrong magic values at the front.  Maybe the IHDR chunk has a '0' set on height (which means 256), or maybe you have to calculate height from width and total pixels.  Maybe color types are encoded wrong, or bit depths are encoded wrong, by some other program.  Maybe they are missing the IEND chunk, but you can determine that from external data.  Maybe the PLTE is wrong.  Maybe the wrong values are used for some of the chunk names.  Like most formats, errors that the tested reader doesn't die on can be distressingly common.

Comment: @Yakk and in such cases do you really (really?) would implement a new png library? I would correct the errors and use libpng. In your example: you first correct the magic bytes then read the chunk (using libpng functionality) and correct the height, color types and bit depths. You can use libpng to read chunks and you can add your own chunks if necessary.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini sure -- because I'm also decoding those chunks using a FPGA (which I mentioned above).  So now I'm parsing the file's large-scale structure and correcting errors in it (no point in using libpng for that part), and doing the low-level parsing within chunks (decompression, etc) in hardware.  I didn't say any *one* of that myriad of mess was sufficient to reimplement png -- I listed all of them for a reason.  You asked what a 'flying car' would look like in this context: it isn't realistic, but there are always extreme cases.